# How to check if _data is defined?

Tags: collection, collection-filtering

This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('orderhandling/paymentmapper')->getCollection();
$payments = $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', $id);
```

Sometimes, if the id is not defined, the _data array in $payments is not defined. How can I check if it is not defined? I tried isset, but thats always false, no matter if the array is defined or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you make sure $id is defined before getting your collection, otherwise it's a waste of time/resources

Comment: `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Collection_Db_Abstract::_data` is always defined. Also, note that it is protected.

Answer (score 1):

I am making an assumption here but if your id field is the tables unique id then you can simply do the following:

```
$payments = Mage::getModel('orderhandling/paymentmapper')->load($id);
```

Otherwise I would always check that `$id` is set before doing anything to avoid errors like the one mentioned in your question.